# Can't go online in Studio5000

Tags: plc

Im new learning PLC programming and I'm trying to connect to a PLC but It does not appear in the "Who active" window but if I look for the PLC in the RSLinx it appears in there, anybody can help me with this?

Im trying to go online to troubleshoot the PLC

[image: RSLinx]

[image: Who Active window]

Answer (score 0):

In your RSLinx Classic screenshot, you are seeing the PLC using a driver named "AB_ETH-1_ERHWSC".

However, in your Studio5000 Who Active screenshot, the driver you are looking at is named "AB-ETHIP-1".  In addition, Studio5000 is not currently using RSLinx Classic, but instead is using FactoryTalk Linx.

You can switch Studio5000 to use RSLinx Classic by going to the Communications menu and selecting "Select Communications Software..."  After you do that, go into Who Active, find the "AB_ETH-1_ERHWSC" driver, and you should be able to see the PLC there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to connect to the PLC.